# Is there a way to get an android image without root?

Tags: rooting, images

I wanna get a raw image from my Android Phone (5.0) to a PC using dd command, but i don't want to root it. So, i'm looking for a way for do it. Sorry about my english and  thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Some Qualcomm phones have a "Download mode" that shows the phone as a raw disk

Comment: If there's a fitting TWRP for your device, you could `fastboot boot twrp.img` (without installing) and thus having a "temporary root" to run the `dd`.